# Could not find association :assignments in model User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Creating a ruby on rails site and recently added:

```
<% if (?can :manage, :table) %> 
<%= link_to 'New Table', new_table_path %>
<% end %>
```

for some additional security and now it states that I cannot do this. I think it might have something to do with my abilities which are:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new
       can :read, :all
       if user.role? "admin" 
       can :manage, :all
  end
  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new
       can :read, :all
       if user.role? "coach" 
       can :manage, :all
  end
  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new
       can :read, :all
       if user.role? "captain" 
       can :manage, :tournaments
       can :manage, :results
  end
  def initialize(user)
       user ||= User.new
       can :read, :all
       if user.role? "teammember" 
       can :manage, :individualresults
  end
  end
end
```

Thanks ahead for any help. If you want additional code let me know.

Comment: You should *definitely* not have more than one `initialize` method. You also appear to have an extra `end` at the end.

Comment: so I assigned roles to certain users which is where the "if user.role? "teammember"" etc comes into play. The additional "end" is gone now but I don't think it was affecting anything.

Comment: should I combine all those into a single initialize method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your ability file](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Ability-Precedence) should probably look like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
     user ||= User.new
     can :read, :all
     if (user.role? "admin" || user.role? "coach")
       can :manage, :all
     end
     if user.role? "captain" 
       can :manage, Tournament
       can :manage, Result
     end
     if user.role? "teammember" 
       can :manage, Individualresult
     end
  end
end
```

[Checking a user action against the defined CanCan rules](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities) is done like:

```
if can?(:create, Table)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly. I was also missing a relationship in my roles which I also found.